# If a sequence of self-adjoint linear operators is convergent, show that its limit is self-adjoint.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If a sequence of self-adjoint linear operators is convergent, show that its limit is self-adjoint.

I'm lost on this problem. I don't know how to even start this. Any solutions or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\lim <T_n(x),y> = \lim <x,T_n(y)>$ and note that $<-,->$ is continuous.

Comment: Convergent in what sense?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the function $A \mapsto A - A^*$ is strongly continuous